# django template: access project root path

Tags: django, templates, path, root

I would like to access the root path variable in my template, how can I do that?
So far, I have:

```
{% if user.username == "" and request.path != "/login/" and request.path != "/"  %}
     <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=/login/">
{% else %}
```

I would like to write something like this:

```
{% if user.username == "" and request.path != projectRoot+"/login/" and request.path != projectRoot  %}
     <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=projectRoot+/login/">
{% else %}
```

Should I create and send this projectRoot variable from my view, or is there already a variable for that?

Many thanks in advance,

Romain

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are trying to redirect this way to the login? There are much better ways of doing this (like using the [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the full path of the URl using [`request.full_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path) and write a template tag to check if it contains a string but this is a very bad way of trying to do what you want (redirect when unauthorized).

Instead, you [should decorate your view using `@login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: Interesting! I just tried but it doesn't work. When not logged, I am redirected to http://127.0.0.1/accounts/login/?next=/import/ (due to the LOGIN_URL variable) which is not correct for my application. How to modify LOGIN_URL just once? In the settings file?

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with Timmy that you shouldn't be trying to do this sort of redirection in the template, note that there is an easy way of getting the full URL to a view: and that is using the `{% url %}` tag. That tag (and the `reverse` function in views) is aware of the full path to your site, which it gets from the WSGI environment, so there is no need to pass an extra variable. Since you shouldn't be hard-coding URL paths anyway, using this is a win all round.